# Read each string from comma separated string and display it on a html list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a string of words as below: **home,apple,banana,music,sound**.
Here each word is separated with commas (','). 
**How to extract each comma seperated element from that string and display it on an html list as below using jQuery?**.

```
<ul>
<li>home</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>banana</li>
<li>music</li>
<li>sound</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code

Comment: Don´t agree to the close reason for this question. The moderators must be more flexible. It's a real problem of day-by-day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can parse your string with `.split`, then iterate through every element in your array to create a `<li>` and append it to your `<ul>`.

```js
var str = "home,apple,banana,music,sound";
var array = str.split(',');

$.each(array, function(index, value) {
  $("#myList").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var words = "home,apple,banana,music,sound";

// Explode string and save as array
var explode = words.split(',');
var ul = $("#list");
explode.forEach(function(element) {
  $(ul).append("<li>" + element + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way will be:

- 1.make your string an array, e.g. using split method
- 2.than use $.each or $.map to generate `<li>` tags you want

There is also $.makeArray http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/ you can use

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str = "home,apple,banana,music,sound";

  var arr = str.split(",");
  $.each(arr, function(value, index) {
    $("#xyz").append("<li>" + index + "</li>");
  });

});
```

first split the string using

> split()

then Iterate over it using

> $.each()

and append it to a ul

```
  <ul id="xyz">

  </ul>
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/22/

Answer (score 0):

It will works as follows.

- Just split the string into array using `split()` function having the parameter ',' since here ',' is the seperator.
- Trace that array and append each element of that array into a string.
- Then append the content of that string into the `div` or `ul` tag

```js
var jqueryCode=" home,apple,banana,music,sound";
var res = jqueryCode.split(",");
var htmlUl="<ul>";
$.each(res, function( index, value ) {
//  alert( index + ": " + value );
  htmlUl+="<li>"+value+"</li>";
  
});
$("#result").html(htmlUl);
var htmlUl="</ul>";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?